# How to deal with multiple hierarchy on same dimension table with different leaf node in RPD - OBIEE 11g

Tags: obiee

I have to create two hierarchies

```
 1.) Year-Quarter
 2.) Year-Month, on the same dimension table.
```

As we know,  when we create multiple hierarchies the leaf node should be same in both the hierarchies, in that case guide me how to deal with different leaf nodes on the same dimension table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different logical dimension tables.